# How to have the table total the sum of my measure which has an IF condition

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm creating a table that automatically calculates the bonus for each salesperson based off their sales figures. I'm struggling with the measure

```
Whale Accounts = 
    IF('Oct-Dec Refresh 1.5.23'[YearOverYear Variance] > 
800000 && 'Oct-Dec Refresh 1.5.23'[Percentage Difference] >= 1.1, 2500, 0)
```

Any account that sold over $800,000 and had a sales growth increase of 10%, receives $2500 in bonuses. I created the measure and it shows $2,500 for each account that meets this criteria, but the table doesn't sum it, how can I get the table to sum the total?

Also, both YearOverYear Variance and Percentage Difference are measures. I have attached an image for clarification
[image: Table Image]

I tried creating custom columns, using SUM, CALCULATE but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need a summing iterator over your accounts for this. Something along the lines of:

```
Bonus =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Master Bill To] ) ,
    [Whale Accounts]
)
```

Where the account column is the one you are using in the visualization!

Comment: Thank you for your input Marcus but this is giving me the same thing as my measure, except it showing $125,000 instead of $2,500 and is still no being totaled